# Why $\{(x,x + 2);x \in \text{real numbers} \}$ is not a vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

$$\{(x,x + 2); x \in \mathbb R \}$$

We see that it holds for addition, it also holds for multiplication with scalar, but the solution is that this is not a vector subspace. Why is that so ?

EDIT:
The solution from the comments to my question is:

1.) it doesn't have a null vector, so the equation $x + 2 = 0$ and $x = 0$ cannot satisfy one another.

2.) We cannot prove it for addition since: $((x + y), (x + y) + 4)  \neq ((x + y), (x + y) + 2)$

Comment: How did you show that it holds for addition?

Comment: An easy way to see that is not a subspace is noting that the zero vector is not in the set.

Comment: $(x,x+2) + (y,y+2) = (x+y, x+y+4),$ and $x+y+4 \neq x+y+2)$.

Comment: Addition: $$(x_1, x_1 + 2) + (x_2, x_2 + 2) = ((x_1 + x_2), (x_1 + x_2  + 2) + 2)$$
$$(x_1 + x_2) and (x_1 + x_2 + 2) \in \text{real numbers}$$

@ChrisLeary 
I guess this is a wrong approach from my side then...

Comment: Because it doesn't have the null vector.

Comment: @BiliDebili The second entry of an arbitrary element of that set is exactly the sum of the first entry and $2$, which is not the case with $(x_1+x_2,(x_1+x_2+2)+2)$.

Comment: It's already been pointed out that your set doesn't contain the zero vector  and isn't closed under addition. Either of those two facts alone is enough to make it not a vector subspace, but there's also a third reason: It isn't closed under multiplication by scalars.